# How to set environment variable and execute command in one line (PowerShell)?

Tags: bash, powershell, environment-variables

How can I set value of environment variable and execute command in one line in PowerShell?

I have this:

```
PGPASSWORD=db_pass psql -U db_user -d db_name -a -h localhost -f some.sql
```

and it's working great in Linux.

How can I translate above to PowerShell command which will work on Windows Server 2012 - Windows 10?

I tried:

```
SET "PGPASSWORD=db_pass" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -a -d db_name -h localhost -f some.sql
```

and I get error: "The & is reserved for future use..." - Windows 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
$env:PGPASSWORD='db_pass'; & "C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -a -d db_name -h localhost -f some.sql
```

In reality this is two commands separated by a semi-colon so they can be run as a single line.

Note also that from PowerShell you set environment variables via `$env:<name of var>`.

Comment: Actually this isn't exactly the equivalent of the bash command the question is about because it leaves the environment variable in place after the command is called.  In the bash command, `PGPASSWORD` disappears after the call to psql.

Answer (score 0):

just add a trailing command to the compound list:
`;$env:PGPASSWORD=''`
to get
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.4\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -a -d db_name -h localhost -f some.sql; $env:PGPASSWORD=''`

you might have to pipe add a sleep in there between the command and last reset of the variable, if the command is launched in asynchronous fashion otherwise you might end up resetting the variable before its use by the launched program. Mileage may vary.
It's a hack, but it works better than leaving the password in the environment forever.